# What the Vedas say about marriages?

Tags: vedas, marriage

Can anyone cite hymns about marriages particularly in Vedas? If nothing mentioned about marriages in the Vedas, Smriti or Puranas or Ramayana or Mahabharata references are also accepted in worst case.